# Partial view checkbox value not getting updated in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I have a partial view, which is bound to a collection of data having property called as IsDelete, used to check if the user wants to delete that specific row.

On click of button, the data comes as expected.

The problem arises as I try sorting this collection, suppose I checked the  first row check and now sort the rows, even after sorting still the first row checkbox is shown as checked while the data has moved from first to some other row after perform sorting.

Hence, when I try submitting the page, I am getting that user has selected to delete first row each time in this case, instead of the actual selected row.

Note : I am doing a server side sorting, using linq and then updating the partial view

Comment: Hw do you sort the list? client side or at the server?

Comment: Show us your sorting method.

Comment: I am doing a server side sorting, using linq and then updating the partial view

Comment: Post some code otherwise people would only be guessing as to what might be the problem.

Comment: Checkbox values aren't submitted unless checked?

Comment: It seems if you do a POST and return a View, MVC will in some cases use the data in ModelState instead of the model...

Read the comments in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397352/asp-net-mvc-checkbox-not-updating?rq=1