# Asp.Net MVC 5 Checkbox states do not remain the same for records in a list that are not checked on POST

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view that is displaying records on a table with checkboxes for the user to select and update. However, if I have 3 records in the table, Data[0], Data[1], Data[2] and I select only the checkbox for Data[0] and POST it to the controller, then when the screen is returned Data[1] checkbox now has the state of Data[0] that was submitted (`true`). However the database shows the checkbox value is 0 (false) for Data[1]. My only guess is something with the model binding or I would need to persist the checkbox states some how.

Model

```
public class DrinkingWaterModel 
{
    //contains all properties of the FPDrinkingWater Entity 
    public List<FPDrinkingWater> Data { get; set; } 

    public AlertModel SuccessAlert { get; set; }

    public AlertModel FailureAlert { get; set; }
}
```

GET Method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UnverifiedDrinkingWaterLog(AlertModel 
successAlert, AlertModel failureAlert)
    {
        //get unverified data from the db
        var data = (from s in await Manager.Store.GetAllAsync<FPDrinkingWater>()
                   where s.Verified.Equals(false)
                   select s).ToList();

        //fill the model
        DrinkingWaterModel model = new DrinkingWaterModel
        {
            SuccessAlert = successAlert,
            FailureAlert = failureAlert,
            Data = data
        };

        return PartialView("_UnverifiedFPDrinkingWaterTable", model);
    }
```

The View

```
@model MyApplication.Areas.FP.Models.DrinkingWaterModel
@{
Layout = null;
}
<div>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table id="UnverifiedDrinkingWaterTable" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data.FirstOrDefault().SID)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data.FirstOrDefault().Location)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data.FirstOrDefault().Replicate)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data.FirstOrDefault().CollectionDate)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data.FirstOrDefault().CollectionTime)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data.FirstOrDefault().Collectors)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data.FirstOrDefault().Clorinated)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data.FirstOrDefault().Comments)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Data.FirstOrDefault().Verified)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].SID)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Data[i].SID)</td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].Location)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Data[i].Location)</td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].Replicate)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Data[i].Replicate)</td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].CollectionDate)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Data[i].CollectionDate)</td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].CollectionTime)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Data[i].CollectionTime)</td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].Collectors)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Data[i].Collectors)</td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].Clorinated)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Data[i].Clorinated)</td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data[i].Comments)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Data[i].Comments)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(v => v.Data[i].Verified) </td>
                </tr>
            }

            @if (Model.Data.Count() == 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="@Html.ColumnCount(9)"><em>No Drinking Water data to verify.</em></td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>

@if (verify)
{
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Verifying...">Verify</button>
}
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        makeDataTable('UnverifiedDrinkingWaterTable')
    });
    $('#RefreshDrinkingWater').click();



</script>
```

The POST method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyDrinkingWater([System.Web.Http.FromBody] DrinkingWaterModel model)
    {
        var successAlert = new AlertModel();
        var failureAlert = new AlertModel();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<string> successes = new List<string>();
            List<string> failures = new List<string>();


            foreach (var verifiable in model.Data)
            {
                if (verifiable.Verified != false)
                {
                    verifiable.Verified = true;
                    verifiable.VerifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    verifiable.VerifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;  
                    var result = await Manager.VerifyAsync(verifiable);
                }
             }
        }
        else
        {
            InvalidState(failureAlert);
        }
        //return the GET method to update and refresh the table
        return await UnverifiedDrinkingWaterLog(successAlert, failureAlert);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `Html.BeginForm` inside View? I do not see that in your code.

Comment: Yes it's there. I forgot to grab it above the <div>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value isn't updating because it's being read by `ModelState` and not the model.  [Check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397352/asp-net-mvc-checkbox-not-updating) some [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645479/view-not-updating-after-post) to get a better idea of why this feature exists.  The short version is that typically you only return the exact same page from a `POST` if there is an error that needs to be corrected.  By reading from the `ModelState` you give the user the benefit of keeping their previous input.

Two options to resolve this problem:

1. Call `ModelState.Clear();` in your `HttpPost` action before returning the view.  Personally I would *not* recommend this, but it is an option.
2. If the `ModelState` is valid, follow the Post -> Redirect -> Get pattern and call `RedirectToAction` to your original `HttpGet` method.  If the `ModelState` is *not* valid, then do what you're doing so you can show an error message and keep the user input.

Comment: How would the `RedirectToAction` work with the two overloads?

Comment: You can pass objects into the `RedirectToAction` method.  Personally I only use 1 model per action, but using multiple objects should work fine.  Internally it will build a route dictionary.

Comment: The reason for two models is, say I select 10 records to verify...2 may fail on the update. Granted...there's definitely a better way of handling this, as I'm finding out. But I have a deadline coming up that I need to have something functioning before I consider a total re-write.

Comment: Yeah so you could just pass two objects in as route data in the redirect.  Or you can clear the `ModelState` like I mentioned in 1 above.

Comment: So I've been trying to use the route dictionary and when it reaches the GET method, the SuccessAlert and FailureAlert are both null even though the data is present in RedirectToAction before reaching the GET method. Almost like RedirectToAction looses track of the data.

Comment: What does the request look like?

Comment: `return  RedirectToAction("UnverifiedDrinkingWaterLog", new { successAlert = successAlert, failureAlert = failureAlert});` This is what I replaced after the `return` with. When debugging, successAlert does contain the success string, but when it reaches the GET method, it's null.

Comment: It is unmodified.

Comment: An HTTP redirect includes a 302 (or 301) status code and a location URL.  The browser then makes a request to that URL.  What is the *URL* being requested that results in the model binding not working?

Comment: It doesn't change. Upon submitting a record to Verify the URL doesn't change.
(localhost:56668/FP/DrinkingWater#UnverifiedDrinkingWatersContent) this is the before submit and after submit. The purpose of this Alert Model is to display to the user alerts upon completion of tasks. Kind of like Toast notifications.